# LazyLoadingEnabled false not working

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, dbcontext

I am very confused, and I need help understanding lazy loading. I thought configuring lazy loading false would load an entire object including child elements, but that is not happening for me. Searching through other questions, I could not find an adequate answer.

A server contains a list of supervisors, and each supervisor contains a list of trunks.

```
using (var db = new ProjectDatabase())
{
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var dbServer = db.Servers.Include("Supervisors.Trunks").Single(s => s.Name == ArchiveName);

        Console.WriteLine(dbServer.Supervisors.SelectMany(s=>s.Trunks).Count());
}
```

The above code writes 3 to the console line, which is expected because the server contains 3 supervisors and each supervisor contains 1 trunk.

```
using (var db = new ProjectDatabase())
{
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var dbServer = db.Servers.Single(s => s.Name == ArchiveName);

        Console.WriteLine(dbServer.Supervisors.SelectMany(s=>s.Trunks).Count());
}
```

This code (same as first but without include statement) writes 0 to the console. I thought LazyLoadingEnabled = false would load all supervisors and trunks automatically. There are dozens of different types of child objects I need, so I'm hoping for an elegant solution that doesn't require tons of include statements. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse something.

```
LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

disables all lazy loading. What you need is

```
LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

It tells EF to load all required navigation properties that are used (the moment you call them), and have not been used before.

Comment: Switching false to true yields the same result. My understanding was that LazyLoadingEnabled = true would not load all children, but would only load what is needed. But either way setting it true or false ends up with the console writing 0.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann it does what I said. Please check if it actually contains any data. Usually, if you have lazy loading enabled set to false and try to access a navigation property, EF crashes. It should work the way you've got it configured.

Comment: I agree. But it does not work. When I use the include statement, the console reads 3. When I remove the include statement, it shows 0. This is true with LazyLoadingEnabled = false and LazyLoadingEnabled = true.

Comment: That is weird. I'll think about it but I don't think anything will come to my mind why it acts this way.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann If you use EF Code First, then your DBSet<T> must be declared "virtual" in order to use lazy loading

Comment: Isn't lazy loading where it does not load all of the children? Because I don't want that. I need all of the children loaded when I load an object.

Comment: Please read up how it works. The moment you request the data, it is being loaded. Disabling lazy loading means you **MUST** manually load the dependencies or EF crashes (iirc, or it just returns empty sets). Read: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx This link also confirms momos assumption on what could be the problem. Please check your access keywords.

Comment: This is so confusing. The first line of the article you linked says "Lazy loading is delaying the loading of related data, until you specifically request for it." But you guys are saying that lazy loading immediately loads all children. The article states that eager loading loads everything and lazy loading loads only what you need when you need it. What am I missing here?

Comment: @MatthewHagemann well it loads all the data if(& when) you call count on it. While eager loading loads it the second you call include. Please check your data again

Comment: In short: Lazy Loading --> default, child objects are loaded ONE AT A TIME (seperate data store call for each), only when accessed / Eager Loading --> could predefined using Include() method, executes in one single query